# How to change the src of an image dynamically with media queries in css or sass

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I have a responsive website created with bootstrap and sass. I load the background image in the home page dynamically using bootstrap break points in sass.

At the same page I have other images that load heavily. I have created a way to load images based on `width` such that `<img src='assets/img/myImage?width=500'>` so that I reduce the size based on the viewport. But I coulnd't find a way to control the `src` of the `img` tag in sass file so that I use `@media` query and decide the `width` dynamically.

Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: you may have to use javascript.

Comment: Can I do it with javascript based on the break points ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Try something like`  if (window.innerwidth < 996){ / / Execute this }`

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Images are content, not style. You can't use CSS to change them.

You *can* use media queries to change them, but you need to use [a `<picture>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) to do so, not CSS.

Here is an example from MDN:

> ```
> <picture>
>     <source srcset="/media/cc0-images/surfer-240-200.jpg"
>             media="(min-width: 800px)">
>     <img src="/media/cc0-images/painted-hand-298-332.jpg" alt="" />
> </picture>
> ```

Comment: You can use `srcset` on an `img` element.